# why my objects normals are not correct

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, normals

[image: Normals Issue]

As you can see I have switched viewport to *Normals* but the tree doesn't show it correctly while a sphere that I spawned shows correct normals

I tried recalculating, set by face and the normals are correctly positioned

How to fix this?

[image]

I've attached a edited blend file with a part of this tree

Comment: Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is unanswerable and was put on hold for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Obviously only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly you alone know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Describe in detail what the issue is, supported by [settings screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) with the [edit] button above. Don't post comments or ask a new question, editing will automatically queue it for review so it can be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite accurate to say that you're displaying normals.  What's more accurate to say is, you're using the solid view preview, using matcaps aka sphere maps, using the matcap that looks like a normal map.  That's not necessarily *quite* the same thing as displaying normals.

[image]

We can see that it's using that matcap, but that you have the "Color" on the overlays set to "Material", and you've specified a viewport color for your material, over there on the properties view.  So what Blender is doing is giving you the output of this matcap multiplied with your material's viewport color.  When you make a new mesh, it doesn't have that material, so that matcap will be multiplied with a different color, probably, white.

That may have seemed like splitting hairs when I was saying this wasn't technically a view of your normals, but maybe now its more clear why this wouldn't be a good way to, say, make a fast render of a normal pass.  If you want something that actually *is* a view of your normals, you can switch to a material view and set the render pass to "Normal":

[image]

Comment: Tried doing that but look how it came out in normal pass                                   https://www.flickr.com/photos/195780152@N06/52135985161/in/dateposted-public/             idk how to make a hyperlink out of it so sorry for the mess